# Is There A Shorthand Syntax To Invoke An Optional Closure?

Tags: swift, closures, option-type

We know that in Swift we can do the following:

```
if myHandler = myOptionalHandler
{
   myHandler()
}
```

However, this seems a trifle long winded. Is there a shorter way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a shorter way! Simply execute the optional closure as follows:

```
myOptionalHandler?()
```